# How to transfer all files from one computer to another in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, file-transfer

I have a Kali Linux laptop with a lot of files on it. I have recently bought another computer, and I would like to transfer all of the files easily, including the packages, libraries, etc. This way, it would be easy to continue where I left off on the laptop.

Is this possible? I know Mac OS has Time Machine, and I need a Kali Linux solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about writing the files to an external storage device, which you then attach to the destination computer? If both computers run Linux and are networked, you could use `rsync` to copy them. There are may other solutions.

Comment: Oh ok. I will consider this, thanks!

Comment: Often when installing a new system, you install from scratch and copy over the contents of `/home` from your old machine.  Another option is to make an "image" of your old machine and apply it to your new machine. I've done this a few times.  Assuming simple-hard-drive configurations and hard-drives of the same size, install the new machine's hard-drive in the old machine.  Then `dd` the old machine's drive to the new drive, and then install the new hard-drive back into the new machine.  You may need to run `update-initramfs -u` to get everything working smoothly again on your new machine.